# C++ Console Minesweeper Saving 2D Array Spot

Tags: c++, arrays, console

How do i save the random spot queried by the if(display[rand()%10][rand()%10]=='x')
to put in b in there? How i did it it wont work because the spot is a different and the for loop doesnt work therefore.

```
if(anzeigen[rand()%10][rand()%10]=='x')
{
    anzeigen[rand()%10][rand()%10]='b';

}
```

Comment: well, save `rand()%10` in a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rand` will give you each time you call a different value. So if you wand to be the field in the `if` clause and the field within the `then` clause to be the same, you need to cache the values:

```
int x = rand() % 10;
int y = rand() % 10;
if(anzeigen[x][y] == 'x')
{
    anzeigen[x][y] = 'b';
}
```